# Best Way For naming Variables In JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Shall I use var , const , let in JavaScript when I want to declare variables..?

Comment: [Take a look](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/First_steps/Variables)

Comment: You almost never want "var", or never.  Use "let" always except for big stuff you don't want to change accidentally, for that use "const". Some people use const more liberally for any variable that doesn't change, but I don't bother, I use let 99% of the time. Also be sure to understand how the "scope" works when dealing with variables.

Answer (score -2):

yes you can use let , var and const in javascript to declare variables

Comment: So between the 3 Which one should I go with..?